# How to make 2 different appengine-web.xml point to same set of files

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Currently, I have 2 Java applications in Google App Engine.

```
C:\myapplication1\war\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml
C:\myapplication1\war\*.*

C:\myapplication2\war\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml
C:\myapplication2\war\*.*
```

The content in `C:\myapplication1` and `C:\myapplication2` are exactly the same, except the content of `WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <application>myapplication1</application>
    <version>1</version>
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
</appengine-web-app>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <application>myapplication2</application>
    <version>1</version>
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
</appengine-web-app>
```

Is there any way, I can have `C:\myapplication1\war\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml` and `C:\myapplication2\war\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml` refer to same set of application files?

As having to ensure content of 2 folders always sync (except the `appengine-web.xml` file) is rather cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to simply automate the sync with something like:

[SyncToy](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15155).

Exclude the appengine-web.xml from the sync job and maintain it separately.